# как вытащить заблюренный текст

Tags: python, html, текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как вытащить при парсинге заблюренный текст.Он становиться виден только тогда когда нажать на него кнопку "показать".Тогда его можно пропарсить.А до этого там стоят ххххххх

[image]

Может как то можно извлечь и декодировать номер?

Comment: Одним супом не обойтись?не уже Селениумом придется парсить?

Comment: Да, видимо вам нужен инструмент, который умеет исполнять javascript. Jsoup не умеет исполнять javascript. [Обозначьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1521752/edit) в вашем вопросе метки, какой язык программирования вы используете.

Comment: Или селениум, или реализовать код дешифровки самому, или там вообще может там отдельный запрос делается для получения номера. Кто знает. Вы же даже сайт не назвали.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте разберемся изначально с правилами.

1. Код нужно указывать в формате текста, это очень важно.
2. Обязательно пишите url сайта для полного понимания сути вопроса.

Теперь к самому вопросу.

Сайт исходя фото в вопросе: https://auto.ria.com

Для примера возьмем это объявление: https://auto.ria.com/auto_zero_fxs_34397619.html

Вы пытаетесь получить полный номер телефона из соответствующей графы.

Изначально он имеет вид: `(067) xxx-xx-xx`

Чтобы получить его в полном формате нужно нажать на кнопку 'показать', после выполнится скрипт `javascript:void(0)`, который откроет модальное окно, где будет указан полный номер без `xxx`.

К сожалению, нажать на кнопку «показать» с помощью только `requests` или `beautifulsoup` нельзя, потому что кнопка привязана к клиентской части.

Варианты решения:

1. Используйте библиотеку `selenium`, чтобы имитировать клик по кнопке 'показать'.

Пример запроса:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"C:\path\to")

url = 'https://auto.ria.com/auto_zero_fxs_34397619.html'

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.show-phone.show-phone-pop').click()

page_html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')

phone_element = soup.find('div', {'class': 'popup-successful-call-desk'})
phone_string = phone_element.text.strip()

print(phone_string)

driver.quit()
```

2. Можно использовать API данного ресурса.

Необходимо будет получить API ключ и вот пример готового url для запроса: "`https://developers.ria.com/auto/info?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&auto_id=34397619`"

При выводе ищем данную строку:

```json
"userPhoneData": {
    "phoneId": "34397619",  // id телефона пользователя 
    "phone": "(067) 240 37 13"  // Телефон пользователя
},
```

Удачи в парсинге и задавайте вопросы правильно.